# changing dbt dates names in snapshot

Tags: postgresql, macros, snapshot, dbt, scd

How can I change the default columns name in a snapshot:
dbt_valid_from
dbt_valid_to?

I override the macro default__build_snapshot_table and it is working the first time, but when I re run the snapshot I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: I've provided an answer that should help you resolve the issue. In the future, please include sample code and not just the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 macros you need to override. The first (`build_snapshot_table`) handles the initial creation of the snapshot table, which you've done. The second (`build_snapshot_staging_table`) handles the delta on subsequent runs. You can see this in the dbt-core/snapshot.sql code ([snapshot.sql](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/3ad61d5d810aab8bf7bf7bc38f62d02348839c80/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/materializations/snapshots/snapshot.sql#L31-L40)):

```
  {% if not target_relation_exists %}


      {% set build_sql = build_snapshot_table(strategy, model['compiled_sql']) %}
      {% set final_sql = create_table_as(False, target_relation, build_sql) %}


  {% else %}


      {{ adapter.valid_snapshot_target(target_relation) }}


      {% set staging_table = build_snapshot_staging_table(strategy, sql, target_relation) %}
...
```

Take a look at the [default implementation](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/3ad61d5d810aab8bf7bf7bc38f62d02348839c80/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/materializations/snapshots/helpers.sql#L30) to see what logic you need to replace for renaming the columns. Should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Adam above, there are more macros that you need to override. You should be looking at **snapshot_merge_sql** and **snapshot_staging_table** and also a assert

> {{ adapter.valid_snapshot_target(target_relation) }}

In [this link](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/a0e13561b1e92e46559d68cbea469fb1923b8240/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/materializations/snapshots/snapshot.sql) which you may have to override or remove at all.